# MySQL Static Hash-index

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to prespecify the size of a hash index during the initial table creation.
If I know that I may eventually have 200 million unique keys and I don't want to to come to a halt resizing at 100 million can the size be prespecified.

Do any other free databases support presized hash tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you explain a bit more about your table and storage engine? Explicit `HASH` indexes can only be created for tables based on the `MEMORY` and `NDB` engines (NDB = MySQL Cluster). Assuming you are not using MySQL Cluster, it seems strange you'd be using the `MEMORY` storage engine to store millions of rows.

That said, you can add the `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` hint when creating indexes, which seems to influence the amount of space used for keys: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html However, this has got nothing to do in particular with HASH indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In the [`create table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) statement of mysql you can use the `MAX_ROWS = ...` table parameter with the  `NDB` engine.  This should create a hash of that size.