# Good documentation/reference for MySQL hash index?

Tags: mysql, innodb

The MySQL documentation refers to the possibility of using a Hash Index in certain situations, see for example:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-btree-hash.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-adaptive-hash.html

That is, the Hash Index is supported on a MEMORY table (and NDB; see also [MySQL Static Hash-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051843/mysql-static-hash-index/2051925#2051925)), and that InnoDB can adaptively use a Hash Index if beneficial.

However, the above documentation is a bit sparse. Is there any other good documentation/reference for the particular uses/details of Hash Index in MySQL? The basic hashing behavior is implied, but some more particulars would be nice.

Comment: The documentation seems sufficient, assuming you understand what a hash is and how a hash table works. What, in particular, were you hoping to find that wouldn't be covered by wikipedia?

Comment: Good question. In the section on adaptive hash indexes, it says "InnoDB builds hash indexes on demand for those pages of the index that are often accessed." So natural questions follow: 1) What constitutes "often"? 2) Is there any way to profile this behavior to see when/how often this occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this :

- http://jameshalsall.co.uk/emulating-mysql-hash-indexes-on-myisam-tables/

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't _exactly_ answer the question as given, but practically speaking it's useful to know.